# react navigation stack navigation not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i am using react navigation stack navigation. first snippet is the navigation code. the second is in my login page. after i click a button it goes to HomeScreen. it works prefectly. the third code is for navigate to home page from registration page. but i use the same navigation code to navigate to home page but it's not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from '../components/loginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../components/registerScreen';
import HomeScreen from "../components/HomeScreen";

const MainNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScreen,
      navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
    },
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: () => ({ screenInterpolator: () => null }),
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Login",
    navigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: false }
  }
);


export default MainNavigation;
```

/// login page

```
 var mobile_verified = true;

                   if (response.user.mobile_verified == mobile_verified) {

                     this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

                   }
```

/// registration page

```
finalVerification = (e) => {

    var url = `http://dev.finder-lbs.com:3050/auth/mobile_verify?code=${this.state.verificationCode}`;

    // var data = {
    //     "verification_code": this.state.verificationCode
    // };

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application / json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.log('Error ++++ :', error))
        .then(response => {

          console.log("mobile verified response---> ",response)

          if ( response.status === "mobile verified")
          {
               console.log("ok---------------->>");
               console.log("ouuuuuuuuukkkk",this.props.navigation);
               this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

          }

        })
}
```

Comment: First, add `console.log` inside the `if` statement on registration page to see if you go there inside or not.

Comment: it is going inside if ... i checked it by console

Comment: Now check if you can use `this.props.navigation` there inside `console.log(this.props.navigation`

Comment: it also working ......

Comment: I think you need to show more code in registration page to debug. Cause something outside of `navigation` is blocking it

Comment: did you try reset?
const reset = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: ''Home"})],
      });
this.props.navigation.dispatch(reset);